# MySQL Select All Rows After 1st Row With Matching Value

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select all rows after the first row with a matching value?

I have tried:
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Ate=False ORDER BY Ate ASC LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id>=1stqueryid, Fruit=Blueberry

For example, I have a table with a column of fruits and a boolean that says if they have been ate or not.

ID---Fruit-------------- Ate
**1---Blueberry------True**
2---Orange----------True
**3---Blueberry------False**
4---Peach------------True
**5---Blueberry----- True**
**6---Blueberry------False**
**7---Blueberry------True**

I would want to find the first row that had "Ate" = "False" AND "Fruit" = "Blueberry". Then, select the remaining rows that have "Blueberry".
The result should be:

ID---Fruit---------------Ate
3---Blueberry--------False
5---Blueberry--------True
6---Blueberry--------False
7---Blueberry--------True

Is there a way to consolidate the two queries?

Comment: Don't you have any primary key in that table?

Comment: Maybe you can try UNION https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html ?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Sorry, I have added the ID column. The actual table name is "Messages" and the table structure is "_id INTEGER,  address TEXT, date STRING, body STRING" and I am trying to get all the messages that match an address after a certain date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use subquery to get the first id which meet the condition of

```
fruit = 'Blueberry' AND ate = false
```

the subquery look like this

```
id >= (SELECT id 
              FROM   Table 
              WHERE  fruit = 'Blueberry' 
                     AND ate = false 
              LIMIT  1)
```

this subquery returns the first id of the row which meet the condition

```
fruit = 'Blueberry' AND ate = false
```

the final query look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Table 
WHERE  id >= (SELECT id 
              FROM   Table 
              WHERE  fruit = 'Blueberry' 
                     AND ate = false 
              LIMIT  1) 
       AND fruit = 'Blueberry'
```

[See Screen Shot](https://gyazo.com/39398ea5f66d5d5c6284f6b2bb26c258)

Comment: You learn something new everyday. 1. SQL subqueries 2. I'm an idiot :( 
  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @pjd What does 'id <>' do?

Comment: @pjd dude the problem state that he wants only the records that start when first `fruit = 'Blueberry' AND ate = false ` match record so obviously it is `>=` (equal or greater than) notice that the result are  `3, 5,6,7`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Fruit='Blueberry' ORDER BY Ate ASC
```

This query should fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Not exactly. This query selects all Blueberry rows. Thanks for taking a look though!